# List items keep going to the next line in PHP

Tags: php, newline, forms

I am using a form to submit a list of items that I want to save to a config text file, but these list items should all be on the same line of the text file. Every time PHP breaks apart and puts the list items into the file, however, it automatically adds a new line before the `</li>` tag. Why? How do I prevent this.

CODE:

```
$pro = explode("\n",$_POST["pro"]);
$proo = "<ul>";

for($index=0; $index<count($pro);$index++)
{
    $proo .= "<li>";
    $proo .= $pro[$index];
    $proo .= "</li>";
}

$proo .= "</ul>";

$proo = str_replace("\n","",$proo);
```

**Edit 1**

If I echo `$proo` into the webpage, it looks like this:

```
<ul><li>List Item 1
</li><li>List Item 2
</li><li>List Item 3
</li><li>List Item 4
</li><li>List Item 5</li></ul>
```

Why are there line breaks before each `</li>`?

Somewhere in there, it's adding new lines...

Thanks!

David

Comment: you see the new lines when you view the web page source ?

Comment: No it outputs to a text file, which contains new lines before each `</li>` tag. It's messing up the javascript on the main page so I need to remove the new line characters from this piece.

Comment: add `print_r($pro);`  right after: `$pro = explode("\n",$_POST["pro"]);` and show us the output

Comment: `Array ( [0] => List Item 1 [1] => List Item 2 [2] => List Item 3 [3] => List Item 4 [4] => List Item 5 )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

line breaks can be tricky windows or linux `\n` and or `\r` so i added a trim to remove anything extra after the explode, seems to work. personally i would use a foreach() father than for() but thats just me

```
$_POST["pro"]="1
2
3
4";

$pro = explode("\n",$_POST["pro"]);

$proo = "<ul>";
for($index=0; $index<count($pro);$index++)
{
    $proo .= "<li>".trim($pro[$index])."</li>";
}

$proo .= "</ul>";

echo $proo;
```

output:

```
<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In any system you are using [PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol) will aways equal to the appropriate End-Of-Line-char-sequence.

```
explode(PHP_EOL,$_POST["pro"]);
```

The code above will always work.
The line breaks (PHP_EOL values) are:
Windows: \r\n
*nix: \n
old Apple Macintosh's (new ones are based on unix): \r

[PHP_EOL doc](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol)

Edit:
as pointed out by [Dagon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557846/dagon), browsers are using Windows' line-breaks by default.

```
explode("\r\n",$_POST["pro"]);
```

is the way to go then